# How to show and hide multiple dropdown menus and close by clicking outside with pure javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to generate functionalities where dropdown menu can be shown/hidden by dropdown button click. It will be closed too by click anywhere on the page. But, I can't generate it with pure javascript. Can you please help me?

```js
var dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown');
dropdown.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   // only one dropdown is working!
   e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('show');
}); 
        
document.onclick = function(e){ 
  if(e.target.classList.contains('dropdown-toggle')){ 

    if (e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.contains('show')) {
       // for this line, my dropdown is not opening; but I want to close it too
       // by clicking outside; I am disabling it for now
       // e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('show');

    } 
  }
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
ul:not(.dropdown-menu) > li {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
   <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>  </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown 1
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</li>
        <li class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>  </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown 2
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</li>
        <li class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

I worked with jQuery and never worked with pure javascript selectors. So, please inform me if I implemented bad selection practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is loop through the shown menu items, and if the user isn't clicking on the nav item, hide the dropdown.

For the toggle button selector use .dropdown-toggle. Also your list items should be links not li with href.

```js
var dropdown = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-toggle');
dropdown.forEach(function(el){
  el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('show');
  }); 
});


        
document.onclick = function(e){ 
      var _shown = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-menu.show");
        _shown.forEach(function(el){
              if(el != e.target.nextElementSibling && el != e.target.parentNode.parentNode){
                   el.classList.toggle('show');
              }
        });
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
ul:not(.dropdown-menu) > li {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
   <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home 1</a>  </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">About 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown 1
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home 2</a>  </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">About 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown 2
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: second dropdown is not working. I couldn't make it working by the way.

Comment: @user1896653 I was able to get them working and updated my answer. The problem was `querySelector` only selects the first result `querySelectorAll` returns all matching results, so then you just loop through them.

Comment: perfect! can you please explain a bit what have you meant by this: `el != e.target.nextElementSibling` as it might be null? and also `e.target.parentNode.parentNode` means `ul`, right? So, when `el` will not be those two elements, why `toggle` again? Wasn't our intention just `remove` the `show`?

Comment: The if statement makes sure that the drop down only hides when you click outside of the ul and it’s children links .